# View is not updating after changing auto-layout constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

Beforehand I have to say that I actually got the visible effect I've wanted but not in a satisfying way since, right now, constraints need to be "broken" instead of being properly updated.

I got a ViewController which holds a UITableView. The height of that `tableView` can vary from 0 (not visible) to whatever the number of rows it holds is. The height is calculated in the ViewController's viewDidLoad() by multiplying the current number of rows by the row's height.

The first thing I've tried was creating an `@IBOutlet weak var tableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` connected to the height constraint set in the storyboard. It has just some random initial height but it is updated to the correct value within the ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` followed by method that updates the view if needed:

```
tableHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: calculatedTableViewHeight)

// At this point I've tried a variety of methods like the following two but actually none has worked for me
view.layoutIfNeeded()

// or
view.updateConstraints()

// or
view.layoutSubviews()
```

... and even the same methods on tableView just to be sure as well as putting all these in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead.

So what I tried next was to create the same constraint as above but instead of updating I just added it to the view: `view.addConstraint(tableHeightConstraint)`. This actually had the desired visual effect but in the logs I got a conflict of these two height constraints resulting in a break of the initial one. As my goal is to get a correct and clean code I've kept trying. So this time I first removed the constraint from the view before adding the adjusted one again. Visually, again, everything was perfect but I still didn't get rid of the conflicting constraints.

So my actual question is (besides what I was doing wrong so far) how I can - preferably - just update an existing constraint followed by a proper update/relayout of the view and its subviews at any point, whether it is when I first load a view or whether I just want to change some constraints when the user interacts. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Setting the property to a new constraint doesn't remove the old one, it just makes your pointer point to a new one, that's why you're getting conflicting constraints. You should do it like in the answer by @cmyr.

Comment: @rdelmar Ok, got it, thanks for this explanation! But why was there still a conflict when going for `view.removeConstraint(tableHeightConstraint)`, generating a new one and adding it again to the view by `view.addConstraint(tableHeightConstraint)`? Just for understanding reasons...

Comment: What is view in that statement? Is it the controller's self.view? A height constraint that you make in the storyboard is added to the view you setting the height of, the table view in your case (not on the superview). Did you try, self.tableView.removeConstraint(tableHeightConstraint)? The new one should also be added to the table view.

Comment: Right, I performed those methods on the ViewController's view, not on the embedded UITableView! Surprisingly whereas the removal seems to be unsuccessful on self.view, the self.view.addConstraint worked out in a way that the visual effect was the right one.

Comment: Actually, that's not surprising. You can add the height constraint to the superview, though you shouldn't (unless you're making a height constraint that is relative to the superview's size in some way). But of course, you couldn't remove it from the controller's view, because it wasn't there to start with.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Currently, you're assigning a new constraint, instead of updating the current one. The new constraint also hasn't been added to the view hierarchy.

Your approach of using an IBOutlet to reference a constraint you set up in IB is a good approach, but instead of assigning a new constraint to that var, you just need to modify the constraint's constant:

`tableHeightConstraint.constant = calculatedTableHeight`.

You shouldn't need to call layoutIfNeeded() here, since constraints handle calling a layout pass automatically when you change their constants. `updateConstraints()` and `layoutSubviews()` are definitely not what you want.

Comment: I would really like to be able to simply change the pointer to reference a different constraint, to toggle between 2 modes more elegantly.  But it doesn't seem that any update message will cause that newly referenced constraint to replace the previous one.  Am I stuck with having to add and remove the constraints in question each time I want to change modes?

Comment: @Michael: the reference you're holding to the constraint is for your own use; if you add a constraint to a view and don't save a reference to it anywhere, it is still added to the view.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense; easier to understand when you think of constraints on a view simply as an array of items.  A XIB constraint linked to an IBOutlet is just a way to initialize the constraint and add it to the array on first load.  Changing the pointer in your controller doesn't change what's already in the array, whereas changing a property on the constraint (i.e. constant) changes a value and has an actual effect.